# Dagger 2 How to solve constructor dependency

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am an Android developer and trying to learn `Dagger2`. I have gone through some tutorials and got some basic understanding. I developed a basic java app using `Dagger2`. And below is my app code.

**Logger.java:** Logger is simple java class which will print logs with some tag.

```
public class Logger {

    private String tag;

    @Inject
    public Logger(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        System.out.println(tag + "::" + msg);
    }
}
```

**InvertNumber.java:** It will invert the passed number and prints log using Logger

```
public class InvertNumber {

    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    public InvertNumber(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void invert(int i) {
        logger.log("Inverted value is " + (i * -1));
    }
}
```

Now I added `Dagger2` depency classes (Module and component) like below

```
@Module
public class NumberModule {

    private String tag;

    public NumberModule(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Provides
    Logger provideLogger(){
        Logger logger = new Logger(tag);
        return logger;
    }

    @Provides
    InvertNumber provideTempManager(Logger logger){
        return new InvertNumber(logger);
    }
}
```

```
@Component(modules = NumberModule.class)
public interface NumberComponent {

    InvertNumber getInvertNumber();

}
```

Now below is my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumberComponent numberComponent = DaggerNumberComponent.builder()
            .numberModule(new NumberModule("MyMain"))
            .build();

    InvertNumber invertNumber = numberComponent.getInvertNumber();

    invertNumber.invert(10);
}
```

To print logs in console, I have to provide **tag** to the **logger**. For this I am creating instance of `NumberModule` class and passing to NumberComponent builder.

Now my questions are:

1. Is this correct way to pass tag using `NumberModule` instance
2. If it is correct, according to DI concept, it is not encouraged to
   use new operator to create objects (new NumberModule())
3. If the above code is wrong, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of solving problem is right, but there is one more using `@Component.Buidler`. (please, note that in your case `@Inject` annotation in `Logger` and `InvertNumber` constructor not working - you call them by hand).

Rewrite `dagger` stuff like that

```
@Module
public class NumberModule {
    @Inject
    public NumberModule() {}

    @Provides
    Logger provideLogger(@Named("logger_tag") String tag){
        Logger logger = new Logger(tag);
        return logger;
    }

    @Provides
    InvertNumber provideTempManager(Logger logger){
        return new InvertNumber(logger);
    }
}

@Component(modules = NumberModule.class)
public interface NumberComponent {

    InvertNumber getInvertNumber();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder loggerTag(@Named("logger_tag") String tag);

        NumberComponent build();
    }
}
```

and use it

```
NumberComponent numberComponent = DaggerNumberComponent.builder()
            .loggerTag("MyMain")
            .build();
```

To allow `dagger` create `Logger` and `InvertNumber` for you (not manually calling their constructors), you need interfaces for each of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Again here also same thing. You are creating NumberModule instance using new operator which is not encouraged to use in dependency injection. There is no much difference between my code and your code. In your code, you just added one more method to pass loggerTag

Comment: @Chandrakanth, if you add `@Inject public NumberModule() {}` in `NumberModule`, after that you can remove `.numberModule(new NumberModule())` at all - dagger will do it for you

Comment: I didn't understand how to add it. Can you update your answer so that I can understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please point some good tutorials about dagger2

Comment: @Chandrakanth, in my opinion, very good series of acticles about dagger is [that one](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/dagger-2-for-android-beginners-introduction-be6580cb3edb)